# Using Cypress.io to test React in a Maven project

Tags: reactjs, maven, testing, frontend, cypress

I'm currently working on a project and want to use Cypress to write tests for my app that is being made in React. It seems however that Maven is acting up, and after a lot of Google-Fu I got stuck. It seems I'm missing parts of a module, but I was unable to find what kind.[Here is an image of said failure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RssIk.png)

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing package maven compiler plugin reports is inside mozilla rhino jar. Try adding following dependency in to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
    <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This seemed to fix my issue! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @MariusJohanHolmJohansen You’re Welcome